# Cannot access a disposed context instance on GetQueryableAsync

Tags: abp

For some reason when I call
`GetQueryableAsync` I get the error

```
ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed context instance.
```

But in the same class, if I call `GetListAsync` - it works fine - under the hood it looks like both methods are called `GetDbContextAsync` from the `UnitOfWorkDbContextProvider`

Can't figure out why one would work and the other doesn't

I really don't want to use the unit of work at all, so I have this

```cs
    Configure<AbpUnitOfWorkDefaultOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.TransactionBehavior = UnitOfWorkTransactionBehavior.Disabled;
    });
```

My code is like this

```cs
    MyAppService : ApplicationService
    {
       public virtual IEnumerable<Setting> LoadByKey(string key)
        {
            //this works
            return _repo.GetListAsync(x => x.Key.ToUpper() == key.ToUpper()).Result;
        }

        public IQueryable<Setting> GetAll()
        {
            // doesn't work, disposed context error
            return _repo.GetQueryableAsync().Result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try adding `await` to both of your requests

Comment: @AhmadMasoum I did, same issue